# Undefined is not an object - Angular $rootScope.user.userMessage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

I keep getting an error of

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$rootScope.user.userMessage')

with this code:

```
if (typeof($rootScope.user.userMessage) === null) {
```

but if I do have something in $rootScope.user.userMessage it doesn't crash. How can I perform a check to see if this is undefined or null so that the thing doesn't break?

other things i've tried include:

```
if (typeof($rootScope.user.userMessage) === undefined) {
if ($rootScope.user.userMessage === undefined) {
```

Comment: Check if $rootScope.user is not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($rootScope.user && $rootScope.user.userMessage){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typeof is not a function. You have to use it this way

```
if (typeof $rootScope.user.userMessage === "undefined") {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the expression null safe

```
if ($rootScope !=null && $rootScope.user!=null &&  $rootScope.user.userMessage != null) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the $rootScope must be checked. :) Why is that?

Comment: It depends on where you are using the $rootScope

Comment: Unnecessary checks only make the code less clean. In AngularJs you inject the $rootScope and it always has a value.

Comment: How do u know the user injected $rootScope? He didn't posted the complete code.

Comment: The developer injects it, because that is the pattern in angular.

Comment: By looking at the code posted in the question. One can not grantee that the user has followed the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

if you are checking for only undefined you can use

```
angular.isDefined($rootScope.user.userMessage);
```

or

angular.isUndefined($rootScope.user.userMessage);

but the beat practices is to use

```
if($rootScope.user && $rootScope.user.userMessage){
    ...
}
```

it will check both null,undefined or empty within only one condition.

Comment: Would'nt `if($rootScope.user.userMessage)` throw an error if `$rootScope.user` is undefined?

Comment: yes we have to check object first and then inner object element :i have edited answer